# Boost Asio asynchronous: Server sent message to client

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, buffer

I am working on a Server/Client application. Client send a message (header+body) to the Server. The server receives the message, make some modifications and sent it back.

So the client sends the message.

```
async_write (m_socket,boost::asio::buffer(msg -> HeaderData() , msg -> SendLength ()),
    boost::bind ( &Client::HandleSentMessage , this ,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error , boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

The server receives the message.

```
m_socket.async_read_some ( boost::asio::buffer ( *receiveBuffer ) , boost::bind( 
     &ASyncConnectionMT::HandleReceived , shared_from_this() , receiveBuffer , 
     boost::asio::placeholders::error , boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

It goes to my function:

```
void HandleReceived ( BufferPtr receiveBuffer , const boost::system::error_code& ec , size_t size)
```

And there it changes the message received.

```
for ( size_t i=0 ; i!=size ; i++ )
    {
         ((*sendBuffer)[i]) = toupper((*receiveBuffer)[i]); 
    }
```

And sends it back.

```
async_write ( m_socket,  boost::asio::buffer ( *sendBuffer , size ) , m_strand.wrap( 
       boost::bind ( &ASyncConnectionMT::HandleSent ,shared_from_this() , sendBuffer, 
       boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

So far all good. The code is running flawlessly. But what is my problem. I receive the send message and modify it but, lets say for example I want to send back something else. For example a string.

The problem is that I have to pass buffer as `shared_ptr` so my object won't be destroyed after leaving this function.

```
typedef boost::array < char , 65536 > Buffer;
typedef boost::shared_ptr < Buffer > BufferPtr;
BufferPtr receiveBuffer ( new Buffer ) ;
BufferPtr sendBuffer ( new Buffer ) ;
```

I want the client to send me a message like "I am ready" and the server to send  back some information. After the client receives the information, to send a new message to the client that he is ready. So the server can send the next piece of informations. Tried all day, I just can't figure out how to send a string or a char array to client.

Can you show me how to send a string or a char array or to convert them to a shared_ptr ?

Comment: Until now I was able only to give shared_ptr buffer values only with a buffer. boost::array < char , 256 > Buf and for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i ++ ) Buf[i] = '9'; ((*sendBuffer)[i]) = Buf[i] ; any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a string to shared pointer like this if you have c++11:

```
auto shared_string = std::make_shared<std::string>(string_to_send);
```

Or with boost:

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr = boost::make_shared<std::string>(string_to_send);
```

And than send it to socket:

```
async_write(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(*shared_string), m_strand.wrap(boost::bind(&ASyncConnectionMT::HandleSent, shared_from_this() , shared_string, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Note that usualy it is required to send some kind of header, so the client can find out the length of the string. So you can copy string length to `boost::array` and send it to client first, and than send the string itself, for example.